# Aumentar o tamanho da palavra, valor do atributo placeholder dos inputs do tipo text?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Como faço para aumentar o tamanho da palavra, valor do atributo placeholder da tag input do tipo texto?

```
<input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Login" required id="login">
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opção `onFocus` e `onBlur`:

```js
function change() {
  document.getElementById('login').placeholder = 'Alterado';
}

function changeBack() {
  document.getElementById('login').placeholder = 'Login';
}
```

```css
input {
  padding: 12px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  font-size: 16px;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  font-size: 16px;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  font-size: 16px;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  font-size: 16px;
}

input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  font-size: 20px;
}

input:focus::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  font-size: 20px;
}
input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  font-size: 20px;
}
input:focus:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onFocus="change()" onBlur="changeBack()" name="login" placeholder="Login" required id="login">
```

Comment: Muito obrigado rapaziada

Answer (score 2):

Pode ser feito com CSS, a sintaxe muda a depender do navegador. Segue exemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      input:-ms-input-placeholder  {
        font-size:16px;
      }

      input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        font-size:16px;
      }

      input:-moz-placeholder {
        font-size:16px;
      }

 /* firefox 19+ */
      input::-moz-placeholder {
        font-size:16px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
  <form action="demo_form.asp">
    <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Login" required id="login">
  </form>
</body>
```

http://www.cssportal.com/blog/style-placeholder-text/

Comment: Mão na roda hein. Muito obrigado @CamiloSantos

Comment: Vlw @LucasBarbosaFonseca... não esqueça de sinalizar qual solução foi mais adequada para você :)

Answer (score 0):

Bom para aumentar o tamanho da fonte o pessoal já respondeu.

Então para fazer a palavra ocupar mais espaço você pode usar a propriedade `letter-spacing` e atribuir a distância entre as letras que desejar.

```css
input:-ms-input-placeholder{letter-spacing:16px;}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder{letter-spacing:16px;}
input:-moz-placeholder{letter-spacing:16px;}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Login" required id="login"/>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @MagicHat entendi perfeitamente

Comment: @LucasBarbosaFonseca considere validar uma das respostas clicando abaixo das setas de avaliação no icon verde.